# Difference between rotation, symmetry, isometry and isomorphism.

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory

Recently, I've been solving problems involving Burnside's Lemma.
The question often says: "Find all different colorings if we identify colorings when they transform into each other under some rotation/symmetry/isometry/isomorphism."

I get confused about in which cases I need to consider the figure being "turned inside out" like for example tetrahedron can be.
It seems to me that:

1. rotation - no
2. symmetry - yes
3. isometry - yes
4. isomorphism - yes

Assuming it is possible for a given shape.
Is this true? Or it depends?

Comment: What does it mean to say a tetrahedron is "turned inside out"? That is, can you describe what effect this is on the tetrahedron?

Comment: @KCd, if the vertices were numbered, then vertex $1$ goes to $4, 2$ goes to $1$, $3$ goes to $2$, $4$ goes to $3$. What I mean is that the tetrahedron has $12$ different rotations (and only even permutations), but if turned inside out, it has another $12$ (this time odd permutations), which gives a total of $24 = 4!$.